# Debug Gradle app during server startup

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gradle

I've found a lot of posts about debugging Gradle in general, and using IntelliJ IDEA specifically.  But my issue is that the app crashes during startup, and as far as I can tell, IntelliJ won't/can't attach a debugger until after the server has completed starting up.  By the time the server has started all the code I want to debug is already done running, so I can't hit any breakpoints.  Is there a way to force IntelliJ to immediately connect a debugger at launch?  How are you supposed to debug configuration/startup code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a local Tomcat installation.  Using "gradlew tomcatRunWar", you can't attach a debugger until after the container is done starting up.  However, using Intellij's Tomcat Server support, you can create a run config that will attach the debugger immediately.  This way you can debug during container startup.